# Does a UK family visa require employment with a UK firm?

Tags: financial, uk-visa

I have dual US/UK citizenship, and I was looking into the visa requirements for moving my wife and children (all exclusively US citizens) to the UK. We would all be moving there from the US at the same time, and it would appear to me that they should apply for 'family of a settled person' visas ("settled" in this case meaning I have the right to settle, even though I am not currently resident).

There is a financial requirement for that visa, detailed [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/469692/Appendix_FM_1_7_Financial_Requirement_August_2015.pdf), and it looks like it can either be satisfied with a bank balance (which we have currently, but haven't had for the requisite 6 months) or through employment. I make more than the required amount for a spouse + 2 children (£24,800), and I have been at the same job for 5+ years.

There are a few categories for qualification, and it seems that I would best match

> **5.2. Category A: With current employer for 6 months or more – overseas sponsor returning to the UK**

There are two parts to that:

> **First**, the applicant’s partner must be in employment at the date of
>   application and have been with the same employer for at least 6 months
>   prior to the date of application.

*Check!*

> **Second**, the applicant’s partner must also have a confirmed offer of
>   salaried or nonsalaried employment in the UK, starting within 3 months
>   of their return.

*Hmmmmm....*

What I was considering (and my supervisor has indicated he is amenable to in the past), is continuing in the same position I have now, but working remotely. It is a US-only company, and while I am expecting to pay UK taxes and insurance (I'm sure I'll have other questions on those fronts soon), I don't know whether this satisfies the second condition.

Does this plan seem workable to get that visa, or would it require me to find a position with a UK firm?

Comment: You could also pursue the Surinder Singh route to move under EU freedom of movement rules.  These rules are much less restrictive.  To do that, you'd have to establish yourself (for at least 6 months, I believe) in another EU country such as Ireland.  This is obviously a bit of a hassle, and only you can decide whether it's more or less of a hassle than moving with your family under UK immigration rules. But you can certainly do it as a self-employed individual (which I assume you'd have to be to continue to work for your US employer).

Comment: I've seen that mentioned elsewhere, and while I find it interesting, I don't think I could sell the family on it - this would be enough of an upheaval as it is. I think the normal route would be best for us - most of our situation is pretty straightforward. I'm just on the lookout for gotchas, but thanks.

Comment: Yeah, after I posted that comment I was thinking: it could be an exciting adventure for some couples, but it's unlikely to be a welcome plan for kids.  I moved a few times as a child, and I hated it at the time.

Comment: But it helped make you into the @phoog you are today.....right? :) The wife is up for anything - it's the kids we're both worried about. As long as they forgive me someday....

Comment: That's absolutely true.  When I was 13 I was very much opposed to the impending move to the big city as it meant leaving my friends.  But within a year or two I came to the conclusion that it was the best thing that could have happened to me.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer on this question, but http://britishexpats.com/wiki/Spouse_Immigration-UK seems pretty comprehensive. Note that the savings values are different to the ones you've listed. Hope it helps.